# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Your client version ${project.version} is too old, please go download the latest version 3.12.2)

Tags: jmeter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

trying to connect JMeter to snowflake and get this error:

> Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Your client version ${project.version} is
>   too old, please go download the latest version 3.12.2)

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you downloaded the latest Snowflake JDBC driver (3.12.2 or 3.12.3):

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-download.html#downloading-the-driver

Put the JAR file into JMeter's classpath:

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath

Enter the correct JDBC driver class: **net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver**

Comment: I have already done that and added them (one at a time) into the lib folder but I still get the same error.

These are the files I downloaded:
snowflake-jdbc-3.12.3-javadoc.jar
snowflake-jdbc-3.12.3-sources.jar
snowflake-jdbc-3.12.3-tests.jar
snowflake-jdbc-3.12.3.jar

Comment: Updated the answer to include all steps

Comment: Can confirm it looks like an issue with either the driver not being installed or the application cannot find it.  If you configure the class paths, that should help.  You can test the JDBC driver in other clients/programs as well. Also, make sure you go through the JDBC Documentation linked in this response and also that your machine meets the JAVA requirements: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/java-install.html

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the javadoc and sources jar files from the JMeter lib folder.